Как, используя curl, загрузить файлы в репозиторий гитхаба
Я через curl создал репозиторий на гитхабе и хочу туда залить файлы в архиве например зип, чтоб на гитхабе это всё было распаковано. Вот в общих чертах задача. Подскажите как сделать.
Например это другой ноутбук и через токен авторизации нужно поместить зип архив уже распакованным в репозиторий, и в идеале загрузить это используя curl.

Если коротко, то скорее всего загрузить zip, что бы он распаковался сам на гитхабе не выйдет никак :-)
в любом случае нужно локально распаковывать файлы.
И дальше я бы советовал использовать git push
Но если хотите, возможность пушить через rest api есть, смотреть здесь. Там есть и пример curl запроса. Но это придется делать для каждого файла отдельно.

Технически git умеет работать через http. Так что можно сформировать правильные запросы и повторить их через curl. Но это конечно будет безумное извращение ради извращения.
